# How to highlight a node in GMF based editor?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-pde, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I am in the process of implementing search functionality in my GMF editor. So what i am planning to do is utilize EMF Search plugin to search within the EMF objects. But when I click on the search result I will be opening the diagram with the node pre-selected.

Is there a way in which I can traverse through all the nodes in a GMF based diagram and highlight a node based on some parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Found the solution in this forum post -

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/734758/

**Quote**

> I did something similar for the YAKINDU Statechart Tools version 2.0.
>   It is a Statechart Tool where you can execute the statechart model,
>   the active states are highlighted in the diagram editor then. (see
>   http://muelder.blogspot.com/2011/09/new-features-in-sct-2-milestone-5.html)
>   for a screenshot.
>
> Technically, all the highlighting stuff is encapsulated in a single
>   class called HighlightingSupportAdapter. Maybe you want to have a look
>   in the code, it is open source. It is a generic HighlightingAdapter,
>   that can be applied to every GMF based editor. A semantic element is
>   passed to the adapter as well as the higlighting color and the
>   highlighting time. Maybe this is a good start for your use case!